# How to define custom templates with foreman's --template option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upstart, foreman

While using the `foreman` gem I'm having some issues where it will not allow me to define a custom template.

For one of my apps I am able to define ~/.foreman/templates/upstart/master.conf.erb and it is read just fine. Yet for another project, no matter what I try, I cannot get a template to evoke properly with forman upstart exportation.

I've attempted many different ways from defining the -t and --template flag with a file with absolute and relative paths to the ~/.foreman approach. Nothing seems to work.

Could you please offer a few demonstrations / scenarios of how the -t flag should be defined with a template in the version controlled directory (such as in config/upstart-master.conf.erb)?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The argument given to `-t` (or `--template`) must be a directory containing 0, 1, 2 or all 3 of:

```
master.conf.erb
process_master.conf.erb
process.conf.erb
```

And not a file itself.

[Initial feature pull request](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/46).  [Pull request to improve docs](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/pull/363) as the current docs only state: "Specify an alternate template to use for creating export files."