# foreman: application doesn't start on RedHat 6.4

Tags: redhat, upstart, foreman

I use [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to run Rails application on RedHat 6.4, but for some reason it just doesn't start it using the command `sudo start myproject` on a server.

Actually, I use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) and the process is fully automated, but even a manual execution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing with `upstart` tasks:

```
[root@server init]# start project-web-1
start: Unknown job: project-web-1
```

I determined the problem. It's in using `setuid` in `foreman`'s [upstart script](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/599d1f93317409d6a92dd52c80216fcf18132643/data/export/upstart/process.conf.erb#L10)

According to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/471957/166579), `setuid` supported from the `initctl` version `1.4`, but RedHat 6.4 has `0.6.5`

```
[root@server ~]$ initctl --version
initctl (upstart 0.6.5)
```

The solution:

1. I used [the modified previous version](https://gist.github.com/dmishh/9f4f7dbd2c783f9d3865) by [msaffitz](https://github.com/msaffitz) of the `upstart/process.conf.erb` and it started working
2. See [how to use a custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612917/541961) for `foreman`